# AC current calculation from wattage and voltage

Tags: power, ac, current-measurement

There is one simple formula to get Current drawn by the appliance i.e `P = V * I`
I am running an appliance its wattage is 1000W as per the specs. It works on the nominal voltage range between 220-240V 50/60Hz (As per the specs).

I used the multimeter to measure the current drawn by the appliance. It's 3.8A.

The AC voltage currently is 224V, but when I plug in the appliance to AC socket it drops by 10V. It's 214V when the appliance is plugged in. Why did the voltage drop?

If we do the math

```
P = V * I
1000W = 214 * I;
I = 1000/214 = 4.16A
```

On the multimeter, it shows 3.8A. Why the difference in values?

Comment: the power plug may not be making a good connection inside the power outlet. you can tell that is the case, if the power plug gets fairly warm after a few minutes of operation.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage dropped because there is a voltage drop in the wiring between the source and wherever you measured the voltage. There are voltage drops in each piece of wire and device between the generator and your appliance, but only the part between your meter and the appliance is large enough to measure. A 10 volt drop is a little more than would be desirable, but probably not too unusual.

The power rating of the appliance should be the maximum that any customer would see. Since your voltage is a little less than the maximum, the power is a little less and the current is a little less. Some appliance would tend to maintain a more constant power with varying voltage but many do not.

Answer (score 0):

When operated at the rated voltage we can expect, \$ I = \frac P V = \frac {1000}{240} = 4.16 A \$.

> If we do the math
> `I = 1000/214 = 4.16A`

No, you've assumed that the heater is constant power. It's not. You can only get 1000 W on a 240 V supply. Instead we can see what the resistance is and calculate expected results for 214 V.

\$ R_{240V} = \frac V I = \frac {240}{4.16} = 57.7\ \Omega;\$

Now assuming for simplicity that the resistance remains constant (which it doesn't because of the positive temperature coefficient of the nichrome wire) we can calculate the expected current and resultant power at 214 V:

\$ I = \frac V R = \frac {214}{57.7} = 3.71\ \text A \$
This is reasonably close to your measured 3.8 A.

\$ P_{214} = VI = 214 \times 3.71 = 794\ \text W \$. You've lost more than 20% of heating capability due to a voltage drop of 26 V (11%).

Remember that power for a resistor is proportional to V<sup>2</sup> and reducing the voltage to 0.89 of it's rated value will result in a power reduction to 0.89<sup>2</sup> = 0.79.

This is why the utility companies financially punish users with poor power factor as the increased current draw causes voltage regulation issues for all users on a branch even if only one is causing the problem.